# Testing iOS peer to peer communication/Bonjour

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing

I am currently starting a project that deals with iOS devices that do p2p communication in the local area network using Bonjour.

I am wondering how one can test the Bonjour and other networked components of an iOS app, whether it be automatic or even manual (ad hoch tests).

Comment: Are you looking for something other than running the app on two devices and seeing if they find each other?

Comment: That would be a first, very helpful step! How to do it on a single Mac?

Comment: Since you want to test an iOS app, you need two iOS devices running your app. You can actually run a single Xcode instance against an app running on two devices allowing you to debug both instances of the app at the same time.

Comment: The problem is: I have no two devices, and I have only a single mac.

Comment: Do you have one iOS device? If your p2p is using WiFi then you do some testing between the app in the simulator and the app on a real device. But if this is bluetooth p2p then you need two real iOS devices.

Comment: I have one device, so that would be feasible. If I could find a second mac, would it be possible to deploy the application on the second's mac simulator?

Comment: Take a look at WiTap -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html. Download the sample code and run it on your iOS device and simulator. It uses Bonjour for two devices to talk to each other.

Comment: @yeesterbunny I don't see any tests there.

Comment: I copied and pasted the URL but for some reason when you click on it, you have to wait like 5 seconds to get redirected. I'm not sure why. After you get redirected, on the top, a little to the left, you'll see Download Sample Code.

Comment: Sure,it's a sample project, but I don't see the relation to testing anyway.